# Cloud Builds Failulre , unable to find logs to see what is going on

Tags: google-cloud-dataflow, google-cloud-build

i am kicking off a dataflow flex template using a cloud build.  In my cloud build file i am attempting to do 3 things

- build an image
- publish it
- run a flex template job using that image
  this is my yaml file

```
substitutions:
  _IMAGE: my_logic:latest4
  _JOB_NAME: 'pipelinerunner'
  _TEMP_LOCATION: ''
  _REGION: us-central1
  _FMPKEY: ''  
  _PYTHON_VERSION: '3.8'

# checkout this  link https://github.com/davidcavazos/python-docs-samples/blob/master/dataflow/gpu-workers/cloudbuild.yaml

steps:
- name: gcr.io/cloud-builders/docker
  args:
    [ 'build'
    , '--build-arg=python_version=$_PYTHON_VERSION'
    , '--tag=gcr.io/$PROJECT_ID/$_IMAGE'
    , '.'
    ]

# Push the image to Container Registry.
- name: gcr.io/cloud-builders/docker2
  args: [ 'push', 'gcr.io/$PROJECT_ID/$_IMAGE' ]



- name: gcr.io/$PROJECT_ID/$_IMAGE
  entrypoint: python
  args:
  - /dataflow/template/main.py
  - --runner=DataflowRunner
  - --project=$PROJECT_ID
  - --region=$_REGION
  - --job_name=$_JOB_NAME
  - --temp_location=$_TEMP_LOCATION
  - --sdk_container_image=gcr.io/$PROJECT_ID/$_IMAGE
  - --disk_size_gb=50
  - --year=2018 
  - --quarter=QTR1 
  - --fmpkey=$_FMPKEY
  - --setup_file=/dataflow/template/setup.py  

options:
  logging: CLOUD_LOGGING_ONLY

# Use the Compute Engine default service account to launch the job.
serviceAccount: projects/$PROJECT_ID/serviceAccounts/$PROJECT_NUMBER-compute@developer.gserviceaccount.com
```

And this is the command i am launching

```
gcloud beta builds submit \
    --config run.yaml \
    --substitutions _REGION=$REGION \
    --substitutions _FMPKEY=$FMPKEY \
    --no-source
```

The error message i am getting is this

```
Logs are available at [https://console.cloud.google.com/cloud-build/builds/0f5953cc-7802-4e53-b7c4-7e79c6f0d0c7?project=111111111].
ERROR: (gcloud.beta.builds.submit) build 0f5953cc-7802-4e53-b7c4-7e79c6f0d0c7 completed with status "FAILURE
```

but i cannot access the logs from the URL mentioned above

I cannot see the logs, so i am unable to see what is wrong, but i stongly suspect somethign in my run.yaml is not quite right
**Note**: before this, i was building the image myself by launching this command

```
gcloud builds submit --project=$PROJECT_ID --tag $TEMPLATE_IMAGE  .
```

and my run.yaml just contained 1 step, the last one, and everything worked fine
But i am trying to see if i can do everything in the yaml file
Could anyone advise on what might be incorrect? I dont have much experience with yaml files for cloud build
thanks and regards
Marco

Answer (score 1):

I guess the pipeline does not work because (in the second step) the container: `gcr.io/cloud-builders/docker2` does not exist (check https://gcr.io/cloud-builders/ - there is a `docker` container, but not a `docker2`one).

This second step pushes the final container to the registry and, it is a dependence of the third step, which will fail too.

You can build the container and push it to the container registry in just one step:

```yaml
steps:
- name: 'gcr.io/cloud-builders/docker'
  args: ['build', '-t', 'gcr.io/$PROJECT_ID/$IMAGE_NAME', '<path_to_docker-file>']
images: ['gcr.io/$PROJECT_ID/$IMAGE_NAME']
```

Comment: Thanks @inigo, i have amended all thenames to be docker. but now i am getting this exception ```Step #0: unable to prepare context: unable to evaluate symlinks in Dockerfile path: lstat /workspace/Dockerfile: no such file or directory```

Comment: i am wondering if it is at all possible to build. and push an image, then run  a flex template in  a single yaml. I got the feeling i need at least 2 files: one for building/pushing the image, and the other for runnign the flex template.

Comment: This second error is from Docker (inside the container). It cannot find the Dockerfile. Maybe you should add its path explicitely in the YAML.

Comment: thanks @inigo.. but still no luck. have added the path of docker file.. same error. There is something then i dont understand. Am i supposed to build the image first by just using the command gcloud builds submit --project=$PROJECT_ID --tag $TEMPLATE_IMAGE  . ?   or  i can just use the yaml to generate the image?  thanks

Answer (score 1):

Ok, sorted, the problem was the way i was launching the build command

this is the original

```
gcloud beta builds submit \
    --config run.yaml \
    --substitutions _REGION=$REGION \
    --substitutions _FMPKEY=$FMPKEY \
    --no-source
```

apparently when i removed the --no-source all worked fine.
I think i copied and pasted the command without really understanding it

regards